# Return status code and body in curl

Tags: curl, http

Is it possible to use curl to call a REST service (POST method) and get:

- The HTTP status code.
- The response body.

Other information like headers, methods, etc. are not relevant for my use case and actually add to the confusion when testing.

For example, I'm doing:

```
$ curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @payload.json localhost:8080/apply
HTTP/1.1 100 

HTTP/1.1 400 
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 42
Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 16:29:18 GMT
Connection: close

Invalid product: product does not exist
```

I know the service is returning `400` that I can see, and also the response error `Invalid product: product does not exist` that I can also see, so that's good.

However, is it possible to get rid of the rest of the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `-i` to display the response headers, you could use `-w`/`--write-out` with a format string containing the `http_code` variable:

```
curl --write-out '%{http_code}\n' ...
```

would print the response status (and a newline) after the body. Check `man curl` for other variables you might find useful.

Comment: Almost perfect! It's displaying the code **after** the body. Do you know how to display it before? If you don't know that's OK, your solution is already good.

Comment: That doesn't seem possible: The man page says "Make curl display information on stdout after a completed transfer", and some of the variables are only available after the transfer is complete anyway. You could write a script that calls curl with `--output` to write the body to a temporary file and then `cat`s that after the `--write-out` result, though.

Comment: Thank you. It's more than useful as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @DonHolgo 's solution, one can add more info in the write-out like this:

```
curl --location 'https://foo.acme.com' \
--request POST \
--write-out '\nhttp_code=%{http_code}\nexitcode=%{exitcode}\n' --silent --show-error \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"foo": "bar","baz":"bim"}'
```

The output in this case is combined with the response from POST:

```
{"requestId":"550aa1ff-0001-bf46-79ae-018cfe00dff7"}
http_code=202
exitcode=0
```

You can capture that in one variable and process 3 things: the POST response (JSON), the HTTP response code, and the exit code from cURL command.